# Different users' edits are amalgamated

Tags: discussion, bug

Revision 3 of https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/83629/revisions is attributed to me.

I edited the question to remove the code formatting and present the quote correctly, and did only that. A short time prior to that, the OP had removed a few words and an apostrophe, but this edit is shown as being down to me, too.

I'm aware that there is a “grace period” before edits become locked. In this case it’s the OP’s edit which is identified as mine, so the (fairly significant) change is unlikely to cause problems; but if I'd been identified as responsible for *another* user’s significant alteration, I’d be rather miffed.

Should **different users’** edits be rolled up in this way?

[I have found [a relevant question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140377/indicate-whether-an-edit-will-be-combined-with-previous-edits) and [another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138194/edit-summaries-of-merged-edits) on MSO but they don't address the question of combining different users’ edits. I'm not sure that [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75945/incorrect-question-edit-attribution) does entirely, either.]

[[Another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make) has also been found and commented on. But that addresses edits "slipped in" between pressing Edit and Save. In my case the edit was completed [and marked as the OP's] before I clicked Edit, and I was still credited with the OP's change. His edit was rolled into mine, and I was credited with the lot. That is, I took over *his* grace period. I don't believe that should happen; if anything his grace period should be curtailed by my edit in order that both versions can be shown separately and available for rollback.]

Comment: I guess the problem is with the system in place. When you edit something, it goes to a queue and takes time before it gets synchronized properly all over the places. I would be glad to see someone from the SE team comment on this.

Comment: Yes, it may need to be migrated to MSO. I'll let the mods sort it if that's the case.

Comment: Looks like a serious bug.

Comment: @AndrewLeach. The SE team do follow up bug reports on the per-site metas to, not just on [MSO].

Comment: It is indeed a known issue with the Stack Excahnge software: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make